# How to limit number of unprocessed Futures in Scala?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I cannot fund if there is way to limit number of unprocessed Futures in Scala. 
For example in following code:

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global    
for (i <- 1 to N) {
  val f = Future {
    //Some Work with bunch of object creation
  }
}
```

if N is too big, it will eventually throw OOM. 
Is there a way to limit number of unprocessed Futures ether with queue-like wait or with exception?

Comment: This is true in general and is not limited to working with just futures.  If you're creating/retaining a large number of objects of any type then you'll eventually run out of memory.  It's your responsibility to limit this as appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the simplest answer is that you can create an `ExecutionContext` that blocks or throttles the execution of new tasks beyond a certain limit. See [this blog post](http://jvns.ca/blog/2016/03/29/thread-pools-part-ii-i-love-blocking/). For a more fleshed out example of a blocking Java `ExecutorService`, here is [an example](https://github.com/swaldman/mchange-commons-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mchange/v3/concurrent/BoundedExecutorService.java). [You can use it directly if you want, the library on Maven Central is [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.mchange%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mchange-commons-java%22).] This wraps some nonblocking `ExecutorService`, which you can create using the factory methods of `java.util.concurrent.Executors`.

To convert a Java `ExecutorService` into a Scala `ExecutionContext` is just `ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService( executorService )`. So, using the library linked above, you might have code like...

```
import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutionContext,Executors}
import com.mchange.v3.concurrent.BoundedExecutorService

val executorService = new BoundedExecutorService(
  Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 ), // a pool of ten Threads
  100,                                // block new tasks when 100 are in process
  50                                  // restart accepting tasks when the number of in-process tasks falls below 50
 )

implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService( executorService )

// do stuff that creates lots of futures here...
```

That's fine if you want a bounded `ExecutorService` that will last as long as your whole application. But if you are creating lots of futures in a localized point in your code, and you will want to shut down the `ExecutorService` when you are done with it. I [define loan-pattern methods in Scala](https://github.com/swaldman/mchange-commons-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mchange/sc/v2/concurrent/ExecutionContexts.scala) [[maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.mchange%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mchange-commons-scala_2.11%22)] that both create the context and shut it down after I'm done. The code ends up looking like...

```
import com.mchange.sc.v2.concurrent.ExecutionContexts

ExecutionContexts.withBoundedFixedThreadPool( size = 10, blockBound = 100, restartBeneath = 50 ) { implicit executionContext =>
    // do stuff that creates lots of futures here...

    // make sure the Futures have completed before the scope ends!
    // that's important! otherwise, some Futures will never get to run
}
```

Rather than using an `ExecutorService`, that blocks outright, you can use an instance that slows things down by forcing the task-scheduling (`Future`-creating) `Thread` to execute the task rather than running it asynchronously. You'd make a `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` using `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`. But [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is fairly complex to build directly.

A newer, sexier, more Scala-centric alternative to all of this would be to check out [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/stream/stream-introduction.html) as an alternative to `Future` for concurrent execution with "back-pressure" to prevent `OutOfMemoryErrors`.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks a lot for the link to the contexts on maven and whatnot!